# Urls issue on Multi Website on Magento 2.2.8

Tags: magento2, multistore, multidomain, magento2.2.8

We have a issue when creating multistore website on magento 2

Issue

We have 3 multi stores one for English language, Spanish and Italy. And among this English is our main site with domain example.com

I had created a new website using magento store and changed the URL of newly created store to abc.com. all created successful using siteground.com/tutorials/magento/multistore/
( add-on Method)

But when I  goto example.com some of the products urls are changed to abc.com domain.

Do you know why,
We are using Magento 2.2.8

Comment: Can you please try: php bin/magento indexer:reindex

Comment: Yeah I run reindex, cache flush , static deploying ..  no fix.. if we remove the new site from stores , then all works good